# Batch convert json links to csv

Tags: dataset, csv

I have a batch of links with the following naming convention:

https://api.cilabs.net/v1/conferences/ws15/info/attendees?page=1; and the page number incrementing.

I would like to extract the data from those web pages into a CSV file.

Comment: How would the csv file look like?  A small example would be nice

Comment: You'll need to write a script to do that! What have you tried so far beside doing in manually?

Comment: name, company, country
john smith, abc, usa

Comment: What's that? If you want to add information to your question please edit it! Your question is not salvageable with the information given.

Comment: @eliasah I guess the OP wants to build a crawler for scraping the data into a csv.  The question needs some re-wording to be done!

Comment: @SeanOwen, I have made an edit, rewording the question to make it clear. Please review and accept.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are looking for is a crawler, which can crawl through the web pages and scrape the data for you into a csv file.

I really don't like the idea of giving away the full code. So, I would tell you how it's done. I would use Python for the example.

Define the url of the web page. Leave the last part (`page=`), as it can go into a loop, so that as it needs to be incremented after every page gets scrapped.

Now, identify the [xpaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) of the data which you want to scrape. Store each of them in an array, and keep writing(and appending into a csv)

This is the [code of one such scrapper](https://github.com/Dawny33/Cricket-Analytics/blob/master/Crawler.py) which I have written for a project of mine. Refer to it in case of a road-block. I have used the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library of Python. 
You can use other fancy libraries like [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). But, they are just fancy wrappers over lxml, so it's faster.

Comment: It's a working code (used it for a research project). But, I'd appreciate if you learn the logic from it and code the crawler on your own. It would be a wonderful learning experience.